# suggestion for parsing the text

Tags: c#, parsing, text

I have a text file with some text like this :

```
#rn=three            rutid=svt#
#outgoing#
  sz          sucs        sw-loss     ans-comp    cong        dur-absy    
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000
  dsz         ratpt       ovfl        usg-bsy     usg-ovall   usg-ans     
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
  usg-idle    usg-mnt     usg-inst    usg-flt     usg-cns     usg-lock    
  00008.00    00000.00    00008.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
#incoming#
  sz          sucs        ans-comp    usg-bsy     usg-ovall   usg-ans     
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
  usg-idle    usg-mnt     usg-inst    usg-flt     usg-cns     usg-lock    
  00008.00    00000.00    00008.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  

#rn=board            rutid=svt#
#outgoing#
  sz          sucs        sw-loss     ans-comp    cong        dur-absy    
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000
  dsz         ratpt       ovfl        usg-bsy     usg-ovall   usg-ans     
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
  usg-idle    usg-mnt     usg-inst    usg-flt     usg-cns     usg-lock    
  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
#incoming#
  sz          sucs        ans-comp    usg-bsy     usg-ovall   usg-ans     
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
  usg-idle    usg-mnt     usg-inst    usg-flt     usg-cns     usg-lock    
  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  

#rn=conf6            rutid=svt#
#outgoing#
  sz          sucs        sw-loss     ans-comp    cong        dur-absy    
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000
  dsz         ratpt       ovfl        usg-bsy     usg-ovall   usg-ans     
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
  usg-idle    usg-mnt     usg-inst    usg-flt     usg-cns     usg-lock    
  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
#incoming#
  sz          sucs        ans-comp    usg-bsy     usg-ovall   usg-ans     
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
  usg-idle    usg-mnt     usg-inst    usg-flt     usg-cns     usg-lock    
  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  

#rn=dtimon           rutid=svt#
#outgoing#
  sz          sucs        sw-loss     ans-comp    cong        dur-absy    
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000
  dsz         ratpt       ovfl        usg-bsy     usg-ovall   usg-ans     
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
  usg-idle    usg-mnt     usg-inst    usg-flt     usg-cns     usg-lock    
  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
#incoming#
  sz          sucs        ans-comp    usg-bsy     usg-ovall   usg-ans     
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
  usg-idle    usg-mnt     usg-inst    usg-flt     usg-cns     usg-lock    
  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  

#rn=conf10           rutid=svt#
#outgoing#
  sz          sucs        sw-loss     ans-comp    cong        dur-absy    
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000
  dsz         ratpt       ovfl        usg-bsy     usg-ovall   usg-ans     
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
  usg-idle    usg-mnt     usg-inst    usg-flt     usg-cns     usg-lock    
  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
#incoming#
  sz          sucs        ans-comp    usg-bsy     usg-ovall   usg-ans     
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
  usg-idle    usg-mnt     usg-inst    usg-flt     usg-cns     usg-lock    
  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  

#rn=rconf6           rutid=svt#
#outgoing#
  sz          sucs        sw-loss     ans-comp    cong        dur-absy    
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000
  dsz         ratpt       ovfl        usg-bsy     usg-ovall   usg-ans     
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
  usg-idle    usg-mnt     usg-inst    usg-flt     usg-cns     usg-lock    
  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
#incoming#
  sz          sucs        ans-comp    usg-bsy     usg-ovall   usg-ans     
  0000000000  0000000000  0000000000  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00  
  usg-idle    usg-mnt     usg-inst    usg-flt     usg-cns     usg-lock    
  00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00    00000.00
```

now I want to analyse it and i have to convert it to a list or array.
I have an idea to parse each line with a pattern but I think there is a simple way that I don`t know.
please help me if you have a solution 
I want a c# solution

Comment: Its better if you show us your code. Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer:) Good Luck!

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: The most simple way to write it is to do it yourself (especially since you already have idea how to do it). Otherwise please post your code with detailed explanation of problems you've encountered.

Answer (score 1):

```
int counter = 0;
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
using (StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
{
List<string> items = new List<string>();
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
 {
   if (!line.Trim().StartsWith("#") && !line.Trim().StartsWith("0"))
   {
     string[] arr = line.Split('\t');  //each item
     items.Add(line);                  //or if you want the whole row
   } 

   counter++;
 }    
}
```